# Как правильно написать функцию клика разных элементов не дублируя его

Tags: jquery, css, click

```js
$(".summary_1").click(function(){
 if ($("#hotel-facilities").is(":hidden")) {
   $("#hotel-facilities").slideDown("slow");
   $(".summary_1").addClass("open");
 } else {
  $("#hotel-facilities").hide("slow");
   $(".summary_1").removeClass("open");
 }
});
$(".summary_2").click(function(){
 if ($("#lodging_type").is(":hidden")) {
   $("#lodging_type").slideDown("slow");
   $(".summary_2").addClass("open");
 } else {
  $("#lodging_type").hide("slow");
   $(".summary_2").removeClass("open");
 }
});
```

```css
.details {
 border-top: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
 border-bottom: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.tab_content {
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
 width: 250px;
 user-select: none;
 outline: 0;
}
.is-hidden {
 display: none;
}
.summary_1, .summary_2 {
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 14px 40px;
 position: relative;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.summary_1:before {
 /*-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0);*/
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    will-change: translate,rotate;
}
.summary_2:before {
 /*-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0);*/
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    will-change: translate,rotate;
}

.summary_1:after {
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    will-change: translate,opacity;
}
.summary_2:after {
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    will-change: translate,opacity;
}
.summary_1.open:before{ /* добавочный класс */
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-0deg);
    width:0;
}
.summary_2.open:before{ /* добавочный класс */
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-0deg);
    width:0;
}
.summary_1:after,
.summary_1:before {
 content: "";
 width: 14px;
 height: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 background-color: #37454d;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 opacity: 1;
 left: 21px;
 contain: strict;
}
.summary_2:after,
.summary_2:before {
 content: "";
 width: 14px;
 height: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 background-color: #37454d;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 opacity: 1;
 left: 21px;
 contain: strict;
}
.summary_1, .summary_2:hover {
 background: #ebeced;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary_1" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="hotel-facilities" aria-controls="hotel-facilities" tabindex="0">Hotel facilities</h4>
  <div id="hotel-facilities" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">24-hour reception (4923)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">24-hour room service (286)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Airport shuttle (602)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
      <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Beach umbrellas (2094)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Bungalows (152)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Business center (3052)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
        <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Casino (113)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Concierge (2187)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Conference rooms (2659)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
      <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Convenience store (1219)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary_2" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="hotel-facilities" aria-controls="hotel-facilities" tabindex="0">Type of lodging</h4>
  <div id="lodging_type" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Bed & Breakfast (427)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Camping Site (27)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Hostel (121)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Hotel (8967)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Motel (816)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Pension (243)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Serviced Apartment (493)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Vacation Home (3417)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Vacation Rental (11847)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Всем привет есть 2 блока  и при клике они открываются.Я для каждого блока написал свой класс и свой идендификатор.Мне нужно обьединить как то эти блоки.Чтобы не было дублированного кода.Почему?Потому что в сайте будет 9 таких блоков и для каждого написать `summary_1, summary_2, summary_3, summary_4 ,summary_5` и т.д и дать свой стиль неправильно нужно чтобы был единый класс единый идентификатор если невозможно чтобы код так не дублировался . И все было написано изящно и правильно.

Comment: не в тему: обратите внимание на разметку. id повторяются многократно. Так не должно быть.

Comment: Аа да я пропустил эту часть. Спасибо @Kirill Korushkin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы сами видите, что классы одинаковые, и логика работы одинаковая, то оставьте один класс и все.

```js
$(".summary").click(function(){
    var acSel = '#' + $(this).attr('aria-controls');
    
    // можно так, если исходная анимация не нужна в точности
    // $(acSel).slideToggle('slow');
    // или как в вопросе
    if ($(acSel).is(":hidden")) {
        $(acSel).slideDown("slow");
    }
    else {
     $(acSel).hide("slow");   
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.details {
 border-top: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
 border-bottom: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.tab_content {
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
 width: 250px;
 user-select: none;
 outline: 0;
}
.is-hidden {
 display: none;
}
.summary {
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 14px 40px;
 position: relative;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.summary:before {
 /*-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0);*/
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    will-change: translate,rotate;
}
.summary:after {
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    will-change: translate,opacity;
}

.summary.open:before{ /* добавочный класс */
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-0deg);
    width:0;
}

.summary:after,
.summary:before {
 content: "";
 width: 14px;
 height: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 background-color: #37454d;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 opacity: 1;
 left: 21px;
 contain: strict;
}

.summary:hover {
 background: #ebeced;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="hotel-facilities" aria-controls="hotel-facilities" tabindex="0">Hotel facilities</h4>
  <div id="hotel-facilities" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">24-hour reception (4923)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">24-hour room service (286)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Airport shuttle (602)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
      <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Beach umbrellas (2094)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Bungalows (152)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Business center (3052)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
        <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Casino (113)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Concierge (2187)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Conference rooms (2659)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
      <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hotel-facilities-200" name="hotel-facilities-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Convenience store (1219)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="details">
  <h4 class="summary" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="lodging-type" aria-controls="lodging_type" tabindex="0">Type of lodging</h4>
  <div id="lodging_type" class="is-hidden">
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Bed & Breakfast (427)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Camping Site (27)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Hostel (121)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Hotel (8967)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Motel (816)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Pension (243)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Serviced Apartment (493)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Vacation Home (3417)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
      <label class="checkbox-container grouped">
        <input type="checkbox" id="lodging_type-200" name="lodging_type-200" class="checkbox">
        <span class="label">Vacation Rental (11847)</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: спасибо большое @teran .Проблема была в том что когда был один класс при клике открывались обе окна поэтому я не смог  сам выполнить данную задачу.

Comment: @teran разрешите дополнить:  весь if  в событии click можно заменить на $(acSel).toggle("slow");

Comment: @KirillKorushkin разве toggle и slideToggle и ту же анимацию выезда сверху показывают? но в целом да, конечно, можно на toggle заменить, если это не принципиально автору

Comment: да, ток же сверху. но в его случае добавляется фейд. Можно взять slideToggle, он тютилька в тютильку.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin не про то спросил конечно, имел в виду `hide` и `toggle`. они по разному анимируются. первый и ширину и высоту, второй только высоту. поэтому я не стал менять при написании ответа.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin в целом комментарий в код вставил. спасибо.